# does PageView.builder display only the current index like listview.builder?

Tags: flutter

we know that if we use `listview.builder` so the list `listview.builder` will only cashes the current content that visible in screen in memory and auto dispose the hidden part to avoid memory leak

so my question does the `PageView.builder` work same `listview.builder` In terms of reducing memory consumption, or does it display all content on memory, whether visible or hidden ?